# All network devices not connected (code 45)

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

I have an HP pavilion laptop running Windows 11 Home

For no reason I can tell, today when I went to use my laptop all networking hardware no longer functions, in fact the device manager shows it as not being connected. This is a laptop and there’s nothing to actually connect or disconnect here.

- running `ipconfig` returns nothing at all
- I’ve tried uninstalling and reinstalling drivers already
- These networking devices are hidden and are only made visible in the device manager when I select “show hidden devices”
- Getting properties on a device says it’s not connected and gives a “code 45” message.

A photo of my screen is the best I could manage with no networking available.

[image]

I’ve not installed anything weird, the last time I used this the previous day was just to watch some tutorial videos on Udemy, browse Reddit, etc.

However, it does say that a windows update was applied last night when I was not using the computer. “2023-04 cumulative update for windows 11 version 22H2 for x64-based systems (KB5025239)”

A quick search for that update build number seems to show that I’m not the only one, but it doesn’t seem terribly common either. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1042861/wifi-is-not-working-after-windows-11-22h2-update

———

Update: I’ve now uninstalled the most recent windows update and nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you run the network troubleshooter?

Comment: I did, and it’s no help. It just says I have no properly installed network adapter

Comment: You got a System Restore Point?

Comment: I don’t but I do have th option to reinstall windows. I may try that. I am currently on the phone with HP support, I’ll see what they say first. Thankfully I don’t have many files to back up, I’ve put them on an external usb drive. If I had another computer I’d use it to download my drivers again and install them.

Comment: It is possible that the laptop has a cardreader so you could download the file on your phone and transfer it to the laptop that way.

Comment: Well, this was unexpected.  HP support had me boot into the BIOS, restore the defaults,  and enable network boot.  After that I booted up normally and everything was working again.  I'll say that's for sure something I never would have though to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called Hp's phone support, and their solution was the following:

- Shut down the laptop
- disconnect the power adapter, Hold in the power button for 20 seconds
- Reconnect power adapter, start up laptop and press F10 to enter the BIOS
- Restore the BIOS settings to default
- Go over to the boot options and enable network boot
- Save and exit, the computer starts up normally.

I honestly do not know why that worked, but I'm happy it did.  I never would have thought to try that on my own.

Support is now having me download and install that Windows update that I suspect caused the problem in the first place.  We'll see if that causes the same problem again or not. I'll update with the results here.

---

#### UPDATE

The Windows update installed just fine this time.  HP support called me back to see how things were. I asked why this solution worked.

- He said that the main fix was really restoring the default BIOS settings.  If Windows updates break your drivers, this can sometimes be a good fix since the BIOS are the communication layer between any hardware and any software.  I suppose after this it caused Windows to re-install my missing drivers or something? I'm not entirely sure.
- Regarding the network boot option, he said the purpose of that is so that your Wi-Fi card is enabled immediately after pressing the power button.  I'm not sure I understand why this helps, and maybe it doesn't and is just a failsafe, but it's a good tip to keep in mind I suppose.

Comment: If you can, ask the customer support why this works

Comment: I will. Their support is surprisingly good, the same person is going to call me back tomorrow to follow up with me after this Windows update is applied and I will for sure ask.  I am curious myself.

Comment: Got this bookmarked ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, weird. But I am glad it works! Thanks for sharing with the class.